# jQuery: How do I check a number from string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

there is a class named:

```
<div class="level_11 price_level" style="display: block;">
```

I have a script that runs a browser function.
But I want to run this only when my number in the script is lower than the number from the "level_" div.

I have no idea how to do this. 
Well, there are everytime another number. Sometimes level_4, sometimes level_18, etc.

I need to check the number and say if my number is lower then the number from the level_, then run the script.

```
let setLevel = 3; // Change this to set the building level. Example: let Level = 20 //
let Level = setLevel -1;  // Don't touch this //
let logLevel = Level +1; // Don't touch this //

console.log(`Success ✓ - ${IBuilding.length} buildings left`);

$.each(IBuilding, function(Index, Entity) {
    let BuildingMissing = IBuilding.length - (Index + 1);

    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $.get(`/buildings/${Entity.id}/expand_do/credits?level=${Level}`)
      console.log(`${BuildingMissing > 0 ? BuildingMissing : 'Success ✓ - last building successfully expanded to level: ' + logLevel }`);

      }, Index * 250);
});
});
```

Basically the script request all sites, and every site have another "level_".
On the sites where the "level_" number is higher than the number in my variable, then dont run the script at the site. but run the script at the sites where my number is higher then the "level_"

Can anyone help me out? :/

Comment: This problem would be much easer to address if the element could be modified to have a data field, such as `data-level="11"` on it.  Otherwise you will have to grab the class and strip out the number from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the level number like this:

```js
let classname =  $("div[class^='level']").attr("class").split(" ").filter(getClass);

function getClass(value) {
    return value.startsWith("level_");
}
let level = classname.toString().substr(6);
console.log(level);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="level_11 price_level" style="display: block;">
```

Comment: Yeah, so this works. It logs the number in the class -1

But when i define 
```
let Level = 10;
$.get(`/buildings/${Entity.id}/expand_do/credits?level=${Level}`)
```
Then it should only run this link when the current level on the building (Entity.id is the building id from an API) is lower than my Level variable. So how to do that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Add an `if` statement that compares the levels.

Comment: @kazzyvg I don't see where you have in your script the current level of the building. If it isn't there, wouldn't it be possible to get the building level from the API?

Comment: Hi matthias, no there is no level in the API. There is just the building ID (in this, its hospitals, ID=4)

I can send you the whole script.

Comment: @kazzyvg You wrote "But I want to run this only when my number in the script is lower than the number from the "level_" div", so I assume you have this number to which the level from the div should be compared to.

Comment: Oh, yeah sure. I set the number in my script. Because i want to expand a building in a game. The link to expand is /buildings/${Entity.id}/expand_do/credits?level=${Level}

For example: I want to expand all buildings to Level 10. Then the link for that is:
/buildings/${Entity.id}/expand_do/credits?level=10

The problem is, that script works. But the script also expand buildings that are a higher level than 10. so but i want to expand all buildings to "max" level 10. I dont know why, but the script expand others which are already above my level in the link to random like Level 12, 15 etc.

Comment: @kazzyvg Aren't you able to restrict the calls of this link to levels that are lower than the number you get from the level-div? This script is not in your question, so it's not possible to give any advice. I thought the question was how to get the number from the level div so you can compare it in your script.

Comment: I tried to do if currentLevel < Level { ...
But i get TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
Well, the div class for the Level_ is in another link, not /expand_do/credits?
Its on /expand/

Comment: I tried this: 

if (currentLevel > Level) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $.get(`/buildings/${Entity.id}/expand_do/credits?level=${Level}`)

But i need to check which current level each building has.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on link /buildings/ID/:

[current level of building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ib6p.png)

Maybe I can check the Level from there?
The HTML section for that is:

```
<dd>

        13

          <a href="/buildings/7356983/expand" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Ausbauen</a>


      </dd>
```

Comment: You could get the current level from there like this: parseInt($("dd").text().replace("Ausbauen", "").trim());

Comment: Wow, you are amazing. That worked. I get the current level with that.
So but how to set a let variable to get this number from the parseInt?

Then i can do the if currentLevel < Level { /* then do stuff  */

I am sorry, i am still learning JavaScript and i am new at jQuery.

Comment: Can you do let currentLevel = parseInt($("dd").text().replace("Ausbauen", "").trim()); ?

Comment: yes. i will try that. Lol, i have a book for Javascript, it said i can only do strings and numbers to variables .....

Comment: I did that: 

$.each(IBuilding, function(Index, Entity) {
    let BuildingMissing = IBuilding.length - (Index + 1);
    let currentLevel = parseInt($("dd").text().replace("Ausbauen", "").trim());
console.log(currentLevel);
     if (currentLevel < Level) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $.get(`/buildings/${Entity.id}/expand_do/credits?level=${Level}`)

But i get a console Log "NaN"...
Hmm, maybe because the Level from the parseInt is on another URL

Comment: I would be happy, but I understand when you dont want to do that. But do you want to try help me when i do a google meet? (screencast)
Maybe you can understand it better what I try to do

Comment: No sorry, I don't want to do a google meet. What do you mean with the level from the parseInt is on another URL? Are there 2 different pages/URLs?

Comment: Yes they are. I run the script at /buildings/ID 
I am requesting the URL /buildings/ID/expand_do/credits?LEVEL
And the current level of each buildings are on /buildings/ID/expand

But i really have to say sorry, i found the Level of each building in the API

Comment: No reason for sorry, it's good if you found the level in the API. So can you get it to work now?

Comment: Yes it works! I did this:

let setLevel = 20;
let Level = setLevel -1;

$.each(IBuilding, function(Index, Entity) {
    let currentLevel = Entity.level;
    let BuildingMissing = IBuilding.length - (Index + 1);
     if (currentLevel <= setLevel) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $.get(`/buildings/${Entity.id}/expand_do/credits?level=${Level}`)
      console.log(`${BuildingMissing > 0 ? BuildingMissing : 'Success ✓ - last building successfully expanded to level: ' + logLevel }`);
     
      }, Index * 500); 
 
} else { console.log('no buildings available'); }
}); 
});

Comment: are there any suggestions to make the code i added better?